# product detail page join table with catalog/product and cataloginventory/stock_item in catalog/product table not working

Tags: product, category

i want current product of categories display product in magento.

I Write code for that but it give nothing page in balnk it's give 500 intervel error

```
$products =  Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection();;
$products->joinField(
    'qty',
    'cataloginventory/stock_item',
    'qty',
    'product_id=entity_id',
    '{{table}}.stock_id=1',
    'left'
);
$products->joinField('category_id',
    'catalog/category_product',
    'category_id',
    'product_id=entity_id',
    null,
    'left'
);


$products->addAttributeToFilter('category_id', array('in' => $category_ids));

foreach ($products as $product) {

    echo $product->getId()."<br/>";
    echo $product->getQty()."<br/>";


}





?>
```

when categoryids add multiple id then 500 intervel server error. not get proper result please give proper query.
my $categoryid = `Array ( [0] => 5 [1] => 6 [2] => 16 [3] => 23 [4] => 25 [5] => 27 [6] => 36 )`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am Geeting Answer from Below link
http://myphpinformation.blogspot.in/2015/09/filtering-magento-product-collection-by-multiple-categories-and-Stock-item.html

here code for that

```
$product_id = Mage::registry('current_product')->getId();
    $category_ids = $_product->getCategoryIds();
$collection = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection()
 ->addAttributeToSelect('*')
 ->addAttributeToFilter('entity_id', array('neq' => $product_id))
 ->addAttributeToFilter('status', 1)
 ->addStoreFilter();
$conditions = array();
foreach ($category_ids as $categoryId) {
 if (is_numeric($categoryId)) {

  $conditions[] = "{{table}}.category_id = $categoryId";
 }
}
$collection->distinct(true)
->joinField('category_id', 'catalog/category_product', null, 'product_id = entity_id', implode(" OR ", $conditions), 'inner');
$collection->joinField(
    'qty',
    'cataloginventory/stock_item',
    'qty',
    'product_id=entity_id',
    '{{table}}.stock_id=1',
    'left'
);
```